# Ember action-helper pass reference to the clicked element

Tags: javascript, ember.js, action

I made several attempts to get a referance to the clicked html element, which was triggering the action. Nothing worked and I could find something useful in the web so can you help me here, please?

e.g. I want to have something like

```
//my-component.hbs    
<th {{action "clicked" this}}>click me</th>

//my-component.js
actions: {
    clicked(type, _this) {
        Ember.$(_this).css("color", "red");
    },
```

Comment: notice that manually setting the `style` seems not to be a good idea. have you considered to bind the `style` to a computed property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a closure action:

```
<th onclick={{action "clicked"}}>click me</th>
```

Then you will receive the browser event in your action:

```
clicked(event) {
  let elem = event.target; // this is what you are looking for
}
```

Comment: thanks, I already saw this event parameter, but I didnt know that I have to use it with onclick